# How to append LI to UL as the last element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am creating and populating a list with jQuery and want to add an `li` element dynamically.

I've tried the following but it didnt work for me. Instead the browser crashed. Can anyone help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tophundredwatchlist").hide();

$(".addtophundredwatchlist").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "/watchlisttophundred/",
            success : function(data){
                generateList(data);
            }
        });
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    });

//this section draws the list

function generateList(data)
{
    var raw_tag = "<ul id='listwatchlist' class='listwatchlist'>";
    var add_new = "Add New"
    var json_array = data.json_array;
    for (var json_count = 0; json_count < json_array.length; json_count++)
    {
        var raw_string = "<li id='watchlistitem' class='watchlistitem'>" + json_array[json_count].watch_list_name + "</li>"
        raw_tag = raw_tag + raw_string
    }
    raw_tag =  raw_tag + "<div id='addnew' class='addnew'>" + add_new + "</div>"
    raw_tag =  raw_tag + "<div id='newtext' class='newtext'></div>"
    raw_tag = raw_tag + "</ul>"
    $(".listwatchlist").html(raw_tag)
}

//when i try to add the new li like this my browser crashes
$('.newwatchlisttext').live("keypress",function(event) {
    if(event.which == '13'){
        var watch_list_name = $(this).val();
        /**********************************************************/
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "/addwatchlistfromtophundredajaxhandler/",
            data : "watch_list_name=" + watch_list_name,
            success : function(msg){
                //$("listwatchlist ul").append('<li>' + data.watch_list_name + '</li>');
            }
        });
        /**********************************************************/
        $(".addnew").show()
        $(".newtext").hide()

        }
});
```

Comment: You're nesting DIVs inside a UL. Also, try outputting the string before you put it into the DOM. And use the jQuery syntax of `$('<ul>') ` to create your elems. Will be easier to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. You should replace this line:

```
$("listwatchlist ul").append('<li>' + data.watch_list_name + '</li>');
```

with:

```
$("ul#listwatchlist").append('<li>' + data.watch_list_name + '</li>');
```

Oh and also the nesting the `div` in the `ul` as the other answer points out.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're likely having is the attempted nesting of div's inside of a `ul`, as JohnP said.

But here's an approach to creating dom elements that uses jQuery's built-in functionality that will likely be less error prone.

```
var raw_tag = $("<ul id='listwatchlist' class='listwatchlist' />");
var add_new = "Add New"
var json_array = data.json_array;
for (var json_count = 0; json_count < json_array.length; json_count++)
{
    raw_tag.append(
        $("<li id='watchlistitem' class='watchlistitem' />")
                    .text(json_array[json_count].watch_list_name));
}
//as noted by JohnP you can't really put div's inside a UL, so you'll need to change that
$(".listwatchlist").html(raw_tag)
```

Also, ensure that the id you're giving to your new `ul`, `listwatchlist`, is **unique** in your entire page.  You absolutely cannot have multiple elements with the same id.